# Can abstraction be achieved using interfaces

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstraction

In OOP, abstraction is when we only make useful details available to the user and hide all the implementation details. So, if I have an interface and I implement it in a class then how is this achieving abstraction? I read this article about "[how to achieve 100% abstraction using interfaces](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-abstraction-is-achieved-using-interfaces-in-java)"

If the question sounds off topic or vague then it really is, all I want to know is how is abstraction in oop related to interfaces.

Comment: Hide the implementation details -> That is exactly what an interface does, as the article that you link to explains. So, to anwer your question: Yes. (What exactly is not clear to you?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, if I have an interface and I implement it in a class then how is this achieving abstraction?

Because other code can use that interface *without* knowing how exactly it is implemented. You can even get to the point where the "client" code using the interface has absolutely no idea which class exactly was instantiated.

Meaning: your write code that uses `List<T>`, and that means you really don't think whether that list is actually an `ArrayList` or `WhatEverElseList`.

Comment: So, this means that two different programmers have no idea about each other's implementation of the same interface, is this the kind of abstraction that's happening?

Comment: It is one essential aspect of it.